# How to display historical data and live data from database using Highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

I am having difficulty figuring out how to use Highcharts to get new(live) data from a database.

I have tested the example [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data) and it works great.

I get new data written to the database every 1min. The problem is I can only make it grab the newly inserted data from the database and update the chart every 1min, using the newly inserted data as the new data point. I can't get it to show historical data from the database.

[Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)

Here is the code I´m using at the moment.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var chart;
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var options = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'area',
          zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
        },
        xAxis: {
           type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
        },
        series: [{
           name: 'Download',
           data: []
       }, {
           name: 'Upload',
           data: []
        }]
     }; 
     $.getJSON('data.php', function(json) {
        data1 = [];
        data2 = [];
        $.each(json, function(key,value) {
        data1.push([value[0], value[1]]);
        data2.push([value[0], value[2]]);
        });

        options.series[0].data = data1;
        options.series[1].data = data2;
        chart = new Highcharts.stockChart(options);
     });
  });
</script>

<body>
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

And here is the code for data.php.

```
<?php

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'highchart';  
    $dbuser = '*******';                  
    $dbpass = '*******'; 

    try{

        $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpass);
        $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $ex){

        die($ex->getMessage());
    }

    $stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM trafico");
    $stmt->execute();
    $json = [];
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);
        $json[]= [strtotime($time_1m)*1000, (int)$Tx, (int)$Rx];
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

This is the output I get from data.php.

```
[[1521071984000,1255,91],[1521072190000,1212,92],[1521072241000,1220,93],[ ... ]]
```

This is the graph I get [image: sample graph]

Basically I don't know to how to make the code (this graph) above to update dynamically every 1min with new data points.

Comment: To refresh the data, you'll need to re-run the ajax call periodically and replace the chart data with the results. I believe with high chart you could get just the new data points, ie. pass the highest time value to the script and it returns just the data after that time, and then add the data to the chart.

Comment: One other thing, you probably should limit the select to the time range to be displayed just so you don't get a lot of data that won't be displayed in the chart.

Comment: Ya problem is I can't get it to work with historical data any suggestion on how to go about it?

Comment: I don't quite understand what is the problem here. Are you able to get the historical data from database?

Comment: You said "Ya problem is I can't get it to work with historical data" yet your chart seems to be displaying the data. What do you mean you can't get it to work??? Edit your question and show the table schema.

Comment: You SQL should be returning all of the data in the table. Is data being deleted so that there isn't any "historical" data?

Comment: Okay, The following issues that I experience are I can only get either or one of those functions to work. I can either show historical data fron db and after that I need to press F5 to see new data generated (this is the code im using right now). or I can retrieve the latest written data from db as the following example: https://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server.htm

I'm unable to make it work so that I retrieve existing data from db and write new data every minute there after without having to press F5 to view the following data. PS sorry for the bad Eng..

Comment: Basically I don't know to how to make the code (chart) above to update dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

This is the code I added:

```
  events: {
    load: function requestData() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'live.php',
            success: function(points) {
                var series = chart.series,
                shift;

                $.each(series, function(i, s) {
                    shift = s.data.length > 1;
                    s.addPoint(points[i], true, true);
                });
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);   
                chart.redraw(); 
            },
            cache: false
        });

    }
    }
```

Now I have historical data from my DB and it adds new data point every time there's a new entry in de DB without the need to refresh the page.

Here is is my live.php code:

```
<?Php
header("Content-type: text/json");

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'highchart';  
    $dbuser = '*******';                  
    $dbpass = '*******'; 


    try{

        $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpass);
        $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $ex){

        die($ex->getMessage());
    }

    $stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM trafico");
    $stmt->execute();
    $json = [];
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);
            }
        $json[]= [strtotime($time_1m)*1000, (int)$Tx];
        $json[]= [strtotime($time_1m)*1000, (int)$Rx];

    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

This is the output from live.php:

```
[[1522869181000,872],[1522869181000,54]]
```

and this is how the code looks now

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var chart;
 $(document).ready(function() {

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            time: {
                timezoneOffset: 3 * 60
            }
        });

     var options = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'area',
          zoomType: 'x',
          events: {
            load: function requestData() {

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'live.php',
                    success: function(points) {
                        var series = chart.series,
                            shift;

                        $.each(series, function(i, s) {
                            shift = s.data.length > 1;
                            s.addPoint(points[i], true, true);
                        });
                        setTimeout(requestData, 1000);   
                        chart.redraw(); 
                    },
                    cache: false
                });

            }
            }
        },
        title: {
        },
        xAxis: {
           type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
        },
        series: [{
           name: 'Download',
           data: []
       }, {
           name: 'Upload',
           data: []
        }]
     }; 
     $.getJSON('data.php', function(json) {
        data1 = [];
        data2 = [];
        $.each(json, function(key,value) {
        data1.push([value[0], value[1]]);
        data2.push([value[0], value[2]]);
        });

        options.series[0].data = data1;
        options.series[1].data = data2;
        chart = new Highcharts.stockChart(options);
     });
  });
</script>

<body>
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```